# Creating A Menu programmatically DevExpress

Tags: windows, devexpress

How to create a menu dynamically?

In detail I want to:

- Create a new ribbon page (tab, I think it's called ribbon page)
- Next create a title for the page
- Next add 2 ribbon groups and add titles to them
- Next add 3 bar button items to the first ribbon group

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Ribbon page? Could you give the component name?

Comment: In DevExpress You can make a menu by adding a DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonControl to a form then run designer and add the RibbonPage and RibbonGroups to that page ect...I wanna to all this programically in a load event. All the controls are under the namespace DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim menu As New RibbonControl


    Dim aPage As New RibbonPage("Nicks Page")

    'groups
    Dim aGroup1 As New RibbonPageGroup("1st Group")


    'ADD BUTTONS TO RIBBON GROUP HERE
    Dim i As New DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem()

    i.Caption = "Nicks Button"

    aGroup1.ItemLinks.Add(i)




    Dim i2 As New DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem()
    i2.Caption = "Nicks Other Button"

    aGroup1.ItemLinks.Add(i2)




    aPage.Groups.Add(aGroup1)

    menu.Pages.Add(aPage)

    Me.Controls.Add(menu)
```